# IndexError: tuple index out of range - Creating CSV from dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, index-error

I'm trying to create a csv from a dict, but I'm receiving the following error.  I originally had key names instead of index numbers but it caused an error when I added multiple dictionary values.

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Code:

```
#Create dict file to test
userInfoDict = {'orgID': '17', 'firstName': 'TestFirstName', 'lastName': 'TestLastName', 'emailAddress': 'test@test.com',
                    'phoneNumber': '1234567890', 'isoCountryCode': 'US'}, {'orgID': '27', 'firstName': 'TestFirstName2', 'lastName': 'TestLastName2', 'emailAddress': 'test2@test.com',
                    'phoneNumber': '5384537645', 'isoCountryCode': 'US'}


def create_csv(userInfoDict):
    import csv

    userInfo = open('userInfo.csv', 'w')

    for key in userInfoDict:
        if len(userInfoDict[0]) == 0:
            print('Not a valid user: No orgID')
            return None
        elif len(userInfoDict[1]) == 0:
            print('Not a valid user: No First Name')
            return None
        elif len(userInfoDict[3]) == 0 and len(userInfoDict[4]) == 0:
            print('Not a valid user: No Email or Phone')
            return None
        else:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(userInfo, fieldnames=userInfoDict.keys(), delimiter=',')
            #writer.writeheader()  # If you want to add header
            writer.writerow(userInfoDict)
        return

create_csv(userInfoDict)
```

Comment: `elif len(userInfoDict[3]) == 0 ...` should be `elif len(userInfoDict[2]) == 0`... probably.

Comment: `userInfoDict` looks more like `userInfoTuple` with only two elements.

Comment: That's not a proper dictionary, you're indexing it. It's actually a tuple of len 2. In other words, it's two self-contained dictionaries separated by a comma.

Comment: I suspect that you really want a list of dictionaries, not that tuple of dicts you accidentally created. You can access list or tuple items by index number, but you have to use keys to access dict values; dicts aren't inherently ordered (at least, they weren't prior to 3.6, and even now that's just an implementation detail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `userInfoDict` you provided is a `tuple` of two `dicts`, equivalent to:

`userInfoDict = ({'orgID': '17', 'firstName': 'TestFirstName', 'lastName': 'TestLastName', 'emailAddress': 'test@test.com','phoneNumber': '1234567890', 'isoCountryCode': 'US'}, 
                {'orgID': '27', 'firstName': 'TestFirstName2', 'lastName': 'TestLastName2', 'emailAddress': 'test2@test.com', 'phoneNumber': '5384537645', 'isoCountryCode': 'US'}
)`

Yet you are trying to calculate `len(userInfoDict[3])`. It has no element with index 3, only with indices 0 and 1.

Comment: I see. Yes I originally just had a dictionary set up with this code, but tried to add a second set of information incorrectly. This is what was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your 'userInfoDict' is tuple with length of two.

```
len(userInfoDict)
2
```

But you seem to trying to access 'userInfoDict[3]' and userInfoDict[4] in your code which isn't there.

See below

```
userInfoDict[0]
{'emailAddress': 'test@test.com',
'firstName': 'TestFirstName',
'isoCountryCode': 'US',
'lastName': 'TestLastName',
'orgID': '17',
'phoneNumber': '1234567890'}
```

and

```
userInfoDict[1]
{'emailAddress': 'test2@test.com',
'firstName': 'TestFirstName2',
'isoCountryCode': 'US',
'lastName': 'TestLastName2',
'orgID': '27',
'phoneNumber': '5384537645'}
```

So any index beyond 1 will give you out of index error

```
userInfoDict[2]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Please check your 'userInfoDict'  that is not a dict, it is a tuple.